# "DbComparisonExpression requires arguments with comparable type" error for no apparent reason! How do I fix it?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

I am getting a

```
DbComparisonExpression requires arguments with comparable type
```

error on the following LINQ to Entity query:

```
jobDetails.pdata = db.JobBoardUsers.Where(c => c.id.Equals(jbid)).Select(c => new JobBoardUserProfileModel() { ID = c.id, userid = c.userid, firstname = c.firstname, lastname = c.lastname, PostalCode = c.passcode, phone = c.phone, JobDescription = c.desiredjobtitle, resumetext = c.resumetext, savedresume = c.savedresume }).ToList();
```

With exception of ID (Int), all other columns are Varchar. In EF (Model browser) the ID column shows as Int32 and the rest are String. Also, the table does have a primary key.

Here is the **JobBoardUserProfileModel model**:

```
public class JobBoardUserProfileModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string userid { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string phone { get; set; }
    public string JobDescription { get; set; }
    public string savedresume { get; set; }
    public string resumetext { get; set; }
}
```

It seems like everything aligns perfectly. Why am I getting this error?

Comment: what is the type of `jbid` ? and why not use `c.id == jbid` ?

Comment: Thank you Habib, you found my issue. I hadn't even considered jbid as the possible problem but sure enough it is a string and was supposed to be evaluating against "userid", not "id"!

Answer (score -1):

I'd try using a Typed ToList() on your Linq statement:

```
jobDetails.pdata = db........ToList<JobBoardUserProfileModel>()
```

Without that it's probably returning an untyped List object.